# ubuntu 14.04 boots; login screen freezes: no GRUB menu; unable to access recovery boot mode

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2

I'm new to Ubuntu. Ubuntu 14.04 is the only installed OS on this desktop computer.

Since my last update approx. July 20/2016, I can boot but when I get to the login screen, everything freezes: no mouse and the cursor flashes for a few seconds and stops. the keyboard is dead. I have tried to boot in recovery mode, but I do not get a GRUB menu.

I have to tried and have not been able to disable secure boot in BIOS in my ASUS motherboard: Go to the Advanced Mode (F7) Go in the Secure Boot option under the Boot section, etc, changed to Other OS, saved my new settings and there was no change during boot and no GRUB menu and computer booted up to sign in and frozen out. what else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Important question: Does it freeze *before* you (could) log in? or does it **after** you log in?

If you can do folowing thing before it freeze, try it:
when you see the login screen, do not log in, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>. Now you should see black screen with white words:

> Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS JustinHost tty3
>   JustinHost login:

From here on you can login with username and password, and then install for example xfce.

You can go back to login screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> else try with buttons from <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F8</kbd>.
Once you can log in into that dark abyss tty(teletypewriter) terminal, you can install some other GUI instead of gnome, e.g. kde,xfce,lxde. To install xfce: `sudo apt-get install xfce` and `startxfce4` to start it. You should now be able to see [xfce](http://www.xfce.org/). If you get error and black screen, means it is graphic drivers problems.

## If it freezes before:

What would I do? (I am no expert). Fresh ubuntu installation on new partition, then move all personal data ( /home folder) to new partition, then delete old partition, install all programs (/home should remain all settings), and never update again ;) (or change settings to install only security updates.
Plan:
live-USB Ubuntu : -to rescue most important files (+ another usb to save them on.
- and create new partition: open(install) gparted: resize old partition to make place for new(delete files if not enough space), create new partition (type ext4).

Install Ubuntu : click something else, choose new empty partition, mount point: / ,install.
after install: if you cannot boot into new Ubuntu: go in live-USB, and do boot-repair ([link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) : 2th option, recommend settings). Now you can boot into new Ubuntu.
Move all files from oldpartiiton/home into newpartition/home . Very important to copy hidden files (starting with . ). Remove "oldpartition" and resize back the newpartition.
done. *Use google*.

"but I do not get a Grub menu": 
use live-usb and change grub settings : set timeout to 20 seconds. Now is set to 0, so you dont see any menu. *Use google*.

Comment: my computer freezes before  I log in. I used live-usb to retrieve my files. I wasn't able to repair the boot.i'm going to do a fresh install since I have my files. thx for your help